# What iOS apps will take pictures and not send them to Photo Stream by default?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, icloud, photo-stream

I'm looking for a way to take pictures without them going into the Photo Stream. Rather than have to remember to toggle it on and off as I adore it for my personal pictures, I'm looking for an app that lets me control this.

I don't really care if it stores the photos in it's own storage space or somehow can toggle a "do not send" status before it gets added to the normal camera roll.

Has such software been released for iOS?

I will still want this if Apple releases a way to delete select photos from the stream. I am in the habit of documenting work sites using my phone's camera that I really won't ever want to see in my personal photo stream. I'd rather pay for another app than have to remember to enable/disable the stream in the Settings App before and after a work photo session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Photo Stream backs your Camera Roll, any app that uses its own storage space rather than the Roll should do - and I doubt many have been (or can be) updated to backup *their own storage* to Photo Stream at this early stage.

[I'm a fan of Camera+, myself.](http://campl.us/) It saves photos to its own storage, and lets you push them to the Camera Roll (and, therefore, Photo Stream) if and when you want to.

Comment: HUGE fan of Camera+ here. This is the answer. Plus it's only 99¢. In my experience, Camera+ is also faster to store into its own "Lightbox" than it is to save to the Photo Stream, allowing you to take many pictures in MUCH more rapid succession.